# Spockframework cleanup for GoogleDrive API not working

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-api, google-drive-api, spock

once again I have a googledrive question:
I want to use the Spockframework to test if my GoogleDrive Services work as they should. As far as testing that the Service does what it should, the test works perfectly. My problem ist that after a test is through I want to delete the file I just created on my Drive in the cleanup() method of Spock.

My Code looks like this:

```
    def cleanup() {
    docsService.driveService.files().delete(testID)
    println testID
}

    def "test that new copy Sheet is created"() {
    given:
    String testSlide = "testSlide"

    when:
    testID = docsService.copySheetFromDrive(testSlide)

    then:
    docsService.driveService.files().get(testID) != null
}
```

I debugged the code and the cleanup() method is called and the testID ist also printed perfectly, but the file is not deleted from the drive.

I also tried the cleanup primer :

```
    def "test that new copy Sheet is created"() {
    given:
    String testSlide = "testSlide"

    when:
    testID = docsService.copySheetFromDrive(testSlide)

    then:
    docsService.driveService.files().get(testID) != null

    cleanup:
    docsService.driveService.files().delete(testID)
}
```

the delete method is called, but the file is not deleted again.
The only way I was able to delete the file was to do this:

```
    then:
    docsService.driveService.files().get(testID) != null
    docsService.driveService.files().delete(testID)
```

but this makes the whole point of the cleanup moot.

I'm not sure what else to do, so if anyone got an idea I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any possibility to debug `driveService.files()` (request, response) somehow?

Comment: @Opal not too sure about that. I'll try if I can see something with wireshark tomorrow. But why would it work when I put it in the then: primer, but not in the cleanup: primer

Comment: No idea, really. It may differ somehow.

Comment: One idea that might help you debug this issue: on your `cleanup` section, after you issue the delete, add an `assert` to check if the file still exists. Also, one more sanity check: when you debug, is `cleanup` executed _after_ the `when` section?